# ! LaTeX Error: File `polyglossia.sty' not found

Tags: polyglossia, r, tinytex

I get error as

```
"! LaTeX Error: File `polyglossia.sty' not found.

! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

Error: LaTeX failed to compile ase.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See ase.log for more info.
Execution halted"
```

I tried to installing tinytext again and tidyverse but I couldn't solve the problem.

````
---
title: "Do Joes"
author: 
  - Uer Za
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{polyglossia}
  - \setmainlanguage{turkish}
  - \usepackage{booktabs}
  - \usepackage{caption} 
  - \captionsetup[table]{skip=10pt}
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    fig_caption: yes
    fig_height: 3
    fig_width: 4
    keep_tex: no
    latex_engine: xelatex
    number_sections: yes
    toc: no
geometry: margin=1in
link-citations: yes
urlcolor: blue
fontsize: 12pt
biblio-style: apalike
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````

Comment: I don't know what tinytext and tidyverse are, but what about LaTeX? How did you install it? Polyglossia is part of a standard LaTeX installation.

Comment: `tinyTeX` is TeX Live based. So you can install missing packages using the TeX Live package management tools, e.g., `tlmgr`.

Comment: tinytex only has a minimal set of packages, you probably need something like `tlmgr install polyglossia` to add that

Comment: I try to run r code and want output as pdf when I click run I get that error

Comment: @DavidCarlisle where do i have to write tlmgr install polyglossia

Comment: on the command line although the help page you link to suggests some tlmgr functions are available in  R  as something like `tinytex::tlmgr...`   I don't know R though

Comment: Depending on the OS, there are also some notes about package management in [the TinyTeX FAQ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to).

Comment: I just removed header-includes: section and got text problem is in there I think

Comment: @cabohah I saw that question it's not my answer my Sweawe already is like  that

Comment: Where it must be in this polyglossia.sty ?

Comment: Please add an actually compilable test document to your question and not just a code fragment so we can check if the space in front of `header-includes:` is actually there or not.

Comment: I added @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz

Comment: @RasimDilbani Thanks! You're rmd code is fine. Which operating system do you have?

Comment: Windows 10 Enterprise

Comment: @RasimDilbani Can you try `tinytex::tlmgr_install("polyglossia")`?

Comment: I tried that but it not works